# How to make 2 createSlice with redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

Currently, my redux store is not too organized. I have an authentication slice I created originally and wanted to add another slice for another element. I tried to have 2 separate createSlice saved in their own variable and then used combineReducer and add that to configureStore but it end up not working at all. Below is my current code that is working. As you can see the first 3 reducers is to check the state of authentication, follow by the next 2 is to check the state of a required file uploader. I couldn't find a way to add a required prop to it. Im using filebase64 for that. The last reducer is to add the data of the post after the like button is clicked, so I can retrieve the data of the amount of likes from the state. If there is any optimized way to write these, please give me some insight.

```
import { createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: {
        currentUser: null,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        error: false,
        missingFile: null,
        posts: []
    },
    reducers: {
        login(state, action) {
            state.isLoggedIn = true
            state.error = false
            state.currentUser = action.payload
        },
        logout(state) {
            localStorage.removeItem("userId")
            state.isLoggedIn = false
        },
        loginFailure: (state) => {
            state.error = true
        },
        // to check if image is uploaded to create new post
        missingFile(state) {
            state.missingFile = true
        },
        fileUploaded(state) {
            state.missingFile = false
        },
        // action for after clicking like button
        like(state, action) {
            state.posts = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const authActions = authSlice.actions

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: authSlice.reducer
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please separate your code in different files. Creating a store in a `slice` file is not following the best practices at all.

From what I understood, you're trying to create another slice so just create another file for the slice and do the same thing you have done for the `authSlice`. Then export the reducers in each slice file like this:

**In `authSlice.js`:**

```
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

**In the other slice file:**

```
export default SLICE_NAME.reducer;
```

Then import them in the `store.js` file:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import import authSliceReducer from "WHEREEVER YOU ARE EXPORTING IT FROM";
import import SECONDReducer from "WHEREEVER YOU ARE EXPORTING IT FROM";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authSliceReducer,
    SECOND_ONE: SECONDReducer
  },
});

export default store;
```

Comment: How do you use selector since it in different files now? For example 
```const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.isLoggedIn)```  is showing undefined. Do I need createSelector?

Comment: Remember that your selectors are accessing the top level state, so you'll want: `const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.auth.isLoggedIn)`

Comment: @Jason You can create selectors in the `slice` files like so: `export const selectCurrentUser = (state) => state.auth.currentUser;` Then you import it anywhere you want and access it with useSelector: `const currentUser = useSelector(selectCurrentUser);`

Comment: @Chad for some reason, it didnt work before but I retried it and it working now. thank.